# Insert a paragraph into a list that uses the whole text width

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, paragraphs

I want to insert a paragraph or possibly even a box with a background color into a list that uses the whole `\textwidth`. Something like this:

```
1st item 
   a subitem 1
   b subitem 2

2nd item
   a subitee

\begin{use the full width}
   [ Here the text should use the full text width ignoring the list indent]
\end{use the full width}
   b subitem
3rd item
```

The list is a normal enumerate.

Comment: Related: [How to interrupt/resume a list in LaTeX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348194/how-to-interrupt-resume-a-list-in-latex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a oneliner a very simple command is

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shiftleft}{\hspace*{-\@totalleftmargin}}
\makeatother
```

If you want an environment that takes up the whole width and breaks accross pages define a list

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fullwidth}
    {\par
     \setlength{\@totalleftmargin}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}%
     \list{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}}
     \item\relax}
    {\endlist}
\makeatother
```

Look at example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,1,0}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shiftleft}{\hspace*{-\@totalleftmargin}}
\newenvironment{fullwidth}
    {\par
     \setlength{\@totalleftmargin}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}%
     \list{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}}
     \item\relax}
    {\endlist}
%% colored minipage (do not break across pages!)
\newsavebox{\cminibox}
\newlength{\cminilength}
\newenvironment{cminipage}[1][\linewidth]
    {\setlength{\cminilength}{#1-2\fboxsep}
     \begin{lrbox}{\cminibox}%
     \begin{minipage}{\cminilength}}%
    {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
     \colorbox{shadecolor}{\usebox{\cminibox}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill\par
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item subitem 1

        \shiftleft\colorbox{shadecolor}{A one liner here}

        \item subitem 2
    \end{enumerate}

    \item Item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item subitem 1

        \begin{fullwidth}
        \begin{cminipage}
        This is a long sentence to test if it fills the
        whole line again and again and again.
        This is a long sentence to test if it fills the
        whole line again and again and again.
        \end{cminipage}
        \end{fullwidth}

        \item subitem 2
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Item
\end{enumerate}
\noindent\hrulefill\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `\rlap` command; in the following example I used this idea and the `shaded` environment form the `framed` package to define a command to achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!40}

\newcommand\MyInd[1]{%
\begin{shaded}\rlap{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}}\end{shaded}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 1st item 
  \begin{enumerate}
     \item  a subitem 1
     \MyInd{Here the text is using the full text width ignoring the list indent.}
     \item b subitem 2
  \end{enumerate}
  \item 2nd item 
  \begin{enumerate}
     \item  a subitem 1
     \par\rlap{Here the text is using the full text width ignoring the list indent.}
     \item b subitem 2
  \end{enumerate}
  \item 3rd item 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: the result:

[image]

Comment: @Martin: `\rlap` is a red herring here. `\rlap` is basically `\hbox to 0pt{#1\hss}`. The important thing here is that it's just an `\hbox` in vertical mode and TeX does the usual thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just quit `enumerate` at the right place and use `enumitem`'s `[resume]` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum*[1]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum*[2]

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item \lipsum*[3]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you want no indentation, either don't leave a blank line after `\end{enumerate}` (which is what I have done), or use `\noindent`.