# How can a bring a middle paragraph out of the enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate

When a text is in the enumerate environment, all the text is indented under the numbers. How can I remove the indentation from the text in the middle of the enumerate environment?

This is what I am looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item first\\
\lipsum[1]
\item second\\
\lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has already been asked.

Comment: @egreg I couldn't [find](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=enumitem+resume+is:a) it, but maybe I missed it there.

Comment: @tohecz http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19360/insert-a-paragraph-into-a-list-that-uses-the-whole-text-width I think it would be better to move the answers here to that question and close this as duplicate.

Comment: @egreg Since Bernard's answer here has become just a duplicate of mine, I moved mine there, and I think it can be closed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `enumitem` package, and the `wide` key for the list. To have some paragraphs with default indentation, the simplest is to temporarily leave the enumerate environment and return to it with the `resume` key :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=1em, labelwidth = *,align = left, leftmargin = \dimexpr\labelwidth + \labelsep\relax]
\item first\\
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[4]

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item second\\
\lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you please take a look at edited picture of my question? I want some paragraph have default indentation.

Comment: @Enthusiastic Student: Please look at my modified answer.