# How to write the following section in LaTeX?

Tags: paragraphs, sections-paragraphs, roman-numerals

Suppose I want to write in latex just the following way:

42. Prove that,

    (i)x+y=z

    (ii)a+b=c

    (iii) p+q=r

how to do that? I tried `enumerate` or `itemize` but can't do that exactly, is there any way of doing it? or I've to write it manually?

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show, what you try so far? A Minimal (non)Working Example would help us to help you.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `enumitem` package to make your life easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start=42]
  \item Prove that,
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item $x + y = z$
    \item $a + b = c$
    \item $p + q = r$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But this can also be done with no packages at all:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{41}\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}}
  \item Prove that,
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $x + y = z$
    \item $a + b = c$
    \item $p + q = r$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The `setcounter` command is just to make sure the first list (`enumi`) starts at 42. I set the counter to 41 so that when the first `\item` is encountered, it then adds one to the counter and prints the new value (sc. 42).

```
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}}
```

Gives you the Roman numbers. It redefines the label of the second list (our first nested list) `enumii` to use lowercase Roman numerals (`\roman`).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Au101's  answer, but one alternative to itemize-like  environments could be the `linguex` package. The bonus  are (a) the simplicity of code and (b) the possibility of insert normal full-with paragraphs within main items list, without break the numeration ([a bit more complex with the standard lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19360/insert-a-paragraph-into-a-list-that-uses-the-whole-text-width)).

Usage: Please RTFM ... ahem!, I mean... use `\ex.` for main items, `\a.` to start the first subitem and `\b.` to star any other subitem, a blank line to end the `\ex.` item, and that is all.

The default format use roman numerals in the third level, but is easy to change as you wish:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[two columns]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
% To adapt default format (1) a. ... to 1. (i) ...  
\let\oldalph\alph
\let\alph\roman
\renewcommand{\ExLBr}{} % first level format
\renewcommand{\ExRBr}{.}
\renewcommand{\SubExLBr}{(} % second level format
\renewcommand{\SubExRBr}{)}
 % just to start with item No. 42
\setcounter{ExNo}{41}

\begin{document}

\noindent The are some statements to test the liguex package::

\ex. Prove that,
\a.  $x + y = z$ 
\b.  $a + b = c$ 
\b.  $p + q = r$

Then, maybe $d+e=f$ (or maybe not)

\ex. Basic colors are: 
\a.  Red  \f.  Green  \c.  Blue


\end{document}
```

In case that disturb you the sequence `\a.,\b.,\b.,\b., ...` in source code , you can use  `\a.,\b., \c., ...`  up to `\f.`,    but  are  just  `\b.` synonyms, i.e., the order really does not matter,  except for `\a.`.

Note that normal text after a item will be not indented, unless you add one more blank line.