# How to write in the following manner?

Tags: enumerate, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I'm using `\documentclass[12pt]{exam}` environment, and suppose I want to write in the following way:

[image]

Here is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Find the value of each of the following funcitons:\par
(i) $y=a+b$\hspace{100pt}(ii) $f(x)=c+d$\par
(iii) $y=e+f$\hspace{90pt}(iv) $f(x)=g+h$\par
(v)$f(x)=i+j$\hspace{85pt}(v) $y=k+l$
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

But I think this is not suitable, a lot of adjustments need to do to produce desired output. so there any exact way that I can write it? or, such as using `\part` command how can I write it in above manner?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363888/how-to-write-the-following-section-in-latex

Comment: Something i noticed just now: You have number *v* two times. Unfortunately, stuff like that happens when numbering manually.

Comment: ohh yess ... I also noticed just now, that's my mistake. Anyway thanks @Johannes_B

Comment: Noticed just now, looking at the picture again. We both have `funciton`s  in our examples :-) I wonder what a funkty ton might do.

Answer (score 10):

Combining one of the [examples from the Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/List_Structures&stable=0#Some_special_lists) and the matching package documentation, we get the following.

[image: kvijayExamTasks]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
    counter-format=(tsk[r]),
    label-width=4ex
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question Find the value of each of the following funcitons:\par
    (i) $y=a+b$\hspace{100pt}(ii) $f(x)=c+d$\par
    (iii) $y=e+f$\hspace{90pt}(iv) $f(x)=g+h$\par
    (v)$f(x)=i+j$\hspace{85pt}(v) $y=k+l$
    \question Which one of the entries does not fit with the others?
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task mercury
        \task iron
        \task lead
        \task zinc
    \end{tasks}
    \question Find the value of each of the following funcitons:
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task  $y=a+b$   \task  $f(x)=c+d$ 
        \task  $y=e+f$   \task $f(x)=g+h$  
        \task $f(x)=i+j$ \task $y=k+l$
    \end{tasks}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

An alternative to the `exam` class is using package `exsheets` to create exam papers.  The already mentioned Wikibook gives a very short example of its usage together with package `tasks` to get the following output (from the Wikibook):

[image: WikibooksListsTask]