# Full width mdframed in enumerate

Tags: environments, enumerate, mdframed

I am using `enumerate` to write tutorial problems and would like to include boxed solutions immediately after the problems. I am using `mdframed` for the boxed solutions (along with `environ` so that I have the option to show and hide solutions). However, I would like the `mdframed` environment to be full width, rather than just the width of the enumerate list.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{environ}

\newif\ifhidesoln
\NewEnviron{solution}{\ifhidesoln\else\begin{mdframed}\BODY\end{mdframed}\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[75]
    \begin{solution} 
        \lipsum[75]
    \end{solution}
    \item \lipsum[75]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: MWE showing output of code above]

I have tried ending and resuming `enumerate` within the solution environ like so:

```
\NewEnviron{solution}{\ifhidesoln\else
    \end{enumerate}\begin{mdframed}
    \BODY
    \end{mdframed}\begin{enumerate}[resume]\fi
}
```

However, I receive the error

```
\begin{enumerate} on input line 18 ended by \end{solution}
```

Here is a picture indicating the change I would like to make:
[image: MWE showing change I would like to make]

(Just to be clear, I want the text to move to the left along with the box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the question ["Insert a paragraph into a list that uses the whole text width"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19372). Using the solution linked, I was able to solve my issue.

Here is the MWE working as I hoped:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fullwidth}
    {\par
     \setlength{\@totalleftmargin}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}%
     \list{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}}
     \item\relax}
    {\endlist}
\makeatother

\newif\ifhidesoln

\NewEnviron{solution}{
    \ifhidesoln\else
    \begin{fullwidth}\begin{mdframed}
        \BODY
    \end{mdframed}\end{fullwidth}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[75]
    \begin{solution} 
        \lipsum[75]
    \end{solution}
    \item \lipsum[75]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Working MWE]